# How reduce in javascript work if initial value is array

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

```js
var a = [2,4,5,6,7]
a.reduce((acc,cur,i)=>acc,[])
//result : []
a.reduce((acc,cur,i)=>acc,[0,2])
//result (2) [0, 2]
a.reduce((acc,cur,i)=>acc[0],[0,2])
/*
VM410:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:3
    */
```

why am I getting error for the third one?
Wondering how it works?

Comment: First iteration `acc = [0, 2]` you return `0` (the number). Second iteration `acc = 0`

Comment: your return value on each iteration becomes `acc` for next iteration, so when you do `acc[0] which is 0` so on next iteration you're doing `0[0]` which returns undefined and then `undefined[0]` is syntax error

Comment: @CodeManiac no `0[0]` is fine - it produces `undefined`. Next iteration there us a TypeError because of `undefined[0]`

Comment: @VLAZ ahh thanks for pointing fixed my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduce function works as a for loop, where a variable (acc) gets set at every iteration:

The first two examples you gave:

```
var a = [2,4,5,6,7]

a.reduce((acc,cur,i) => acc, []) 
a.reduce((acc,cur,i) => acc, [0, 2])
```

Are equivalent to assigning the accumulator to itself at each iteration:

```
var acc = []; // [0, 2] in the second one

for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
    acc = acc;
}
```

Whereas your last example:

```
a.reduce((acc,cur,i) => acc[0], [0, 2])
```

Is equivalent to assigning to *acc* its first value at each iteration:

```
var acc = [0, 2];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    acc = acc[0];
}
```

Each iteration will assign to *acc* its first value.
The first iteration will look like this:

```
acc = [0, 2];
i = 0

acc = acc[0] // 0;
```

The second iteration will then look like this:

```
acc = 0;
i = 1

acc = acc[0] // undefined;
```

Now *acc* has been assigned the value *undefined* as there is no such property *0* in the value held by *acc*.
The third iteration will, therefore, look like this:

```
acc = undefined;
i = 2;

acc = acc[0]; // Error, no property '0' of undefined.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not return an array. However, the accumulator will be set to that value. So while you assume that `acc` is an array, it is not after the first call to the accumulation function.

What you can do instead is something along the following lines:

```js
    var a = [2,4,5,6,7]; 
    a.reduce((acc,cur,i) => {
            acc.push(cur);
            console.log(`iter ${i}, acc = ${JSON.stringify(acc)}.`);
            return acc;
       }
      ,[0,2]
    );
```

Just make sure that your callback returns an array upon each invocation.

Answer (score 1):

An excerpt from mdn documentation for Array.reduce

> **initialValue** -A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initialValue is supplied, the first
>   element in the array will be used as the initial accumulator value and
>   skipped as currentValue. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an
>   initialValue will throw a TypeError.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce